# Ploting data in geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial, spatial, geopandas

I am working on Kaggle Global Terrorism Database (https://www.kaggle.com/START-UMD/gtd/download) and I am trying to use geopandas for visualization.

I am also using countries dataset (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-admin-0-countries/)

```
import seaborn as sns
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style = "ticks", context = "poster")
from shapely.geometry import Point


countries = gpd.read_file("C:/Users/petr7/Desktop/ne_110m_admin_0_countries/")
countries = countries[(countries['NAME'] != "Antarctica")]
countries.plot(figsize = (15, 15))
```

using code above I can easily plot entire Europe,

after that I import kaggle terrorist dataset and define it as geopandas dataframe

```
DF = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/petr7/Desktop/gtd/globalterrorismdb_0718dist.csv", encoding='latin1')
crs = {"init": "epsg:4326"}

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip ( DF["longitude"], DF["latitude"])]
geo_DF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(DF, geometry = geometry)
geo_DF.head()
```

Until this point everything is working and dataset can be inspect

NOW when I try to plot it it return nonsense plot:

```
geo_DF.plot()
```

I am prety new to geopandas so I wanted to ask what I am missing and also how would you plot entire europe map (countries.plot) and above that terrorist attacks?

[PICTURE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xlW8.png)

Comment: Can you show your data? What `geo_DF.head()` shows? The code itself looks okay. What does it mean nonsense plot?

Comment: ´´´geo_DF.head() ´´´ show head of dataframe with works

Comment: just added printscreene

Comment: You have to set crs to gdf. `geo_DF = gpd.GeoDataFrame(DF, geometry=geometry, crs=crs)`. That might work. But it is a bit strange.

Comment: thank you, but still even with crs set it returns same plot as in Picture attached - no change

Comment: Thank you Very mutch works perfectly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the data. `DF["longitude"].min()` gives -86185896.0.

```
DF.loc[DF["longitude"] == DF["longitude"].min()]
```

As you can see if you run the snippet above, row with the error is 17658.

It seems to be missing comma. If you do

```
DF.at[17658, 'longitude'] = -86.185896
```

before generating geometry, it will work. Or you can drop the row if you are not sure what is exactly wrong with the data.